# JAXB Customizations and List<Object>

Tags: java, jaxb

I used JAXB to create some classes from an XSD. The result was not quite what I expected
and most probably it can be customized.

It created a generic list instead of 3 different lists. Can this be corrected somehow?

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "M1", type = M1_Type.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "M2", type = M2_Type.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "M3", type = M3_Type.class)
})

protected List<Object> m1Orm2OrM3;
```

Is there a customization to fix this?

Comment: What were you expecting? How would you like it to look?

Comment: Man, I would expect 3 different lists:

protected List<M1> m1;

protected List<M2> m2; and so on

Thanks!

Comment: @XmlElement(name = "M1", type = M1_Type.class)
List<M1> m1;

@XmlElement(name = "M2", type = M2_Type.class)
List<M1> m2;

@XmlElement(name = "M3", type = M3_Type.class)
List<M1> m3;

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a repeatable choice, something like

```
<choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
  <element name="M1" .../>
  <element name="M2" .../>
  <element name="M3" .../>
</choice>
```

The answer is negative, there's no such customization. "Three list" is actually a very different data structure.